# How to Create VTKPolyData from VTKImageData (surface extraction)?

Tags: c++, vtk

Given a vtk image:

---

`vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> VTKImage = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();`

---

which is a 3D image that contains a segmentation result as binary data (segmented object = 1, background = 0), 
How could I extract the surface of the segmented object and save it as VTKpolyData?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal working example would be something like this.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMarchingCubes> surface = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMarchingCubes>::New();

#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
surface->SetInput(volume);
#else
surface->SetInputData(volume);
#endif
surface->SetValue(0, 0.5);
surface->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> poly = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
poly = surface->GetOutput();
```

Comment: l folllowed the steps found here(https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/surface-extraction-creating-a-mesh-from-pixel-data-using-python-and-vtk/) and got the same result. What is the difference between **vtkmarchingcubes** and **vtkdiscretemarchingcubes**?

Comment: When it comes to 2d image and polygon, you may refer to `vtkMarchingSquares` which is the 2d marching cube.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is so useful

Answer (score 2):

Use vtkMarchingCubes class. there are some examples [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Modelling/ExtractLargestIsosurface) and [here](https://www.evl.uic.edu/aspale/cs526/final/3-5-2-0.htm)