# How to render a simple 2D vtkImageData object in Paraview?

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I would like to use Paraview to plot simple 2D meshes with either different colors per cell or different colors per vertices. As far as I can tell, the Paraview documentation does not explain how to `Show()` a user-defined VTK object.

I read from the [Paraview guide](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/understandingData.html) how the VTK data model works and from the [VTK User's Guide](https://vtk.org/vtk-users-guide/) how to generate a `vtkImageData` object.

From what I could gather, the following code should yield a `vtkImageData` object of a 10x5 2D mesh spanning [0.;10.]x[0.;5.] with 50 blue elements.

But now I don't know how to actually plot it in Paraview.

```py
from paraview import vtk
import paraview.simple as ps
import numpy as np
from paraview.vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk

def main():
    # create the vtkImageData object
    myMesh = vtk.vtkImageData()
    myMesh.SetOrigin(0.,0.,0.)
    myMesh.SetExtent(0,10,0,5,0,0)
    myMesh.SetSpacing(1.,1.,0.)

    # create the numpy colors for each cell
    blue = np.array([15, 82, 186], dtype=np.ubyte)  # 8 bits each [0, 255]
    npColors = np.tile(blue, (myMesh.GetNumberOfCells(), 1))

    # transform them to a vtkUnsignedCharArray
    # organized as 50 tuples of 3
    vtkColors = numpy_to_vtk(npColors, deep=1, array_type=vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR)

    # allocate the sets of 3 scalars to each cell
    myMesh.AllocateScalars(vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 3)  # set 3 scalars per cell
    myMesh.GetCellData().SetScalars(vtkColors)  # returns 0, the index to which
                                                # vtkColors is assigned
    # Something... generate a proxy using servermanager??

    ps.Show(myMesh?)
    ps.Interact()  # or ps.Render()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

From what I could gather is that I have to apply a geometric filter first, such as `vtkImageDataGeometryFilter()`. But this does not exist in `paraview.vtk`, only by importing the `vtk` module directly.

Another option, according to [this VTK C++ SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899801/how-to-create-vtkpolydata-from-vtkimagedata-surface-extraction) is using `vtkMarchingSquares`.

Either way, apparently `paraview.simple.Show` only accepts a proxy object as input. Which then begs the question of how to create a proxy out of the filtered `vtkImageData` object? To be honest, I have not quite grasped how the visualization pipeline works, despite reading the docs.

Thus far I've only found ways of visualizing VTK objects using `vtk` directly via the [Kitware examples in GitHub](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/), without using the higher level features of Paraview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to render it using a `TrivialProducer` object and the method `.GetClientSideObject()`. This interfaces ParaView to serverside objects.

Sources: [the source code](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/_modules/paraview/servermanager.html) and [the tip given by Mathieu Westphal](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/how-to-show-a-simple-vtkimagedata-object/7745/5) from ParaView support.

```
from paraview import simple as ps
from paraview import vtk
from paraview.vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk
import numpy as np

def main():
    # Create an image (this is a data object)
    myMesh = vtk.vtkImageData()
    myMesh.SetOrigin(0., 0., 0.)
    myMesh.SetSpacing(0.1, 0.1, 0.)
    myMesh.SetExtent(0, 10, 0, 5, 0, 0)

    # coloring
    blue = np.array([15, 82, 186], dtype=np.ubyte)
    # numpy colors
    scalarsnp = np.tile(blue, (myMesh.GetNumberOfCells(), 1))
    scalarsnp[[9, 49]] = np.array([255, 255, 0], dtype=np.ubyte)  # yellow

    # vtk array colors. Organized as 50 tuples of 3
    scalarsvtk = numpy_to_vtk(scalarsnp, deep=1, array_type=vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR)
    scalarsvtk.SetName("colorsArray")
    # allocate the scalars to the vtkImageData object
    # myMesh.AllocateScalars(vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 3)  # set 3 scalars per cell
    # myMesh.GetCellData().SetScalars(scalarsvtk)  # do not use this in ParaView!!
    colorArrayID = myMesh.GetCellData().AddArray(scalarsvtk)
    myMesh.GetCellData().SetActiveScalars(scalarsvtk.GetName())

    # TrivialProducer to interface ParaView to serverside objects
    tp_mesh = ps.TrivialProducer(registrationName="tp_mesh")
    myMeshClient = tp_mesh.GetClientSideObject()
    # link the vtkImageData object to the proxy manager
    myMeshClient.SetOutput(myMesh)
    tp_mesh.UpdatePipeline()

    # Filter for showing the ImageData to a plane
    mapTexture2Plane = ps.TextureMaptoPlane(registrationName="TM2P_mesh", Input=tp_mesh)

    renderViewMesh = ps.CreateView("RenderView")
    renderViewMesh.Background = [1, 1, 1]
    renderViewMesh.OrientationAxesVisibility = 0
    display = ps.Show(proxy=mapTexture2Plane, view=renderViewMesh)
    display.SetRepresentationType("Surface")
    display.MapScalars = 0  # necessary so as to not generate a colormap
    ps.Interact()  # or just ps.Render()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

`ProgrammableSource` is what you want to use. See [this example](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/pythonProgrammableFilter.html#reading-binary-2d-image) or [this](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/pythonProgrammableFilter.html#python-algorithm)